# Barracuda SSL VPN Managing Users

Tags: database, login, user-management, barracuda

Not really sure if this is the right site to be posting on, but I have a question about my Barracuda SSL VPN.  I know there is a built-in user database on the VPN.

Is there some way (in my asp.net source code) to check what users are logged in to the VPN, or if a certain user is logged in?  I guess the more general question is: How do I access the database on the VPN?